# recall form value not working for textareas

Tags: forms, cookies

Im trying to modify this script

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/formremember2.htm

to work for textareas, and not just input text boxes. Heres what im guessing are the relevant parts of the script, i just cant figure it out myself

```
rememberForm.prototype.savevalues=function(){ //get form values and store in cookie
for (var i=0; i<this.fields.length; i++){
if (this.fields[i].type=="text")
this.cookiestr+=this.fields[i].fname+":"+escape(this.fields[i].value)+"#"
}
if (typeof this.togglebox!="undefined"){ //if "remember values checkbox" is defined
this.persistdays=(this.togglebox.checked)? this.persistdays : -1 //decide whether to       save form values
this.cookiestr=(this.togglebox.checked)? this.cookiestr+"toggleboxid:on;" :   this.cookiestr
}
else //if checkbox isn't defined, just remove final "#" from cookie string
this.cookiestr=this.cookiestr.substr(0, this.cookiestr.length-1)+";"
setCookie(this.cookiename, this.cookiestr, this.persistdays)
}

rememberForm.prototype.recallvalues=function(){ //populate form with saved values
var cookievalue=getCookie(this.cookiename)
if (cookievalue!=""){ //parse cookie, where cookie looks like:  field1:value1#field2:value2...
var cookievaluepair=cookievalue.split("#")
for (var i=0; i<cookievaluepair.length; i++){
if (cookievaluepair[i].split(":")[0]!="toggleboxid" && this.getfield(cookievaluepair[i].split(":")[0]).type=="text")
this.getfield(cookievaluepair[i].split(":")         [0]).value=unescape(cookievaluepair[i].split(":")[1])
else //else if name in name/value pair is "toggleboxid"
this.togglebox.checked=true
}
}
```

Comment: You do realize that is impossible to read!

Answer (score 0):

The method `persistfields(id, ...)` sets the fields you want to persist in the cookie. The fields are looked up by `id` so I guess adding a `textarea` with an `id` attribute would suffice.

For example:

```
<form id="myFormId">
    <input type="text" id="someInputId" />
    <textarea id="textareaId"></textarea>
</form>

<script>
    var f = new rememberForm('myFormId');
    f.persistfields('someInputId', 'textareaId');
</script>
```

This will add the input and textarea to the `rememberForm` instance `fields` property.

---

**UPDATE**

The problem lies in this method of `rememberForm`. I formatted the code for readability since the original source has horrible formatting.

```
rememberForm.prototype.savevalues = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {

        // PROBLEM: only allows type="text"
        if (this.fields[i].type == "text") {
            this.cookiestr += this.fields[i].fname + " : " + escape(this.fields[i].value) + "#"
        }
        if (typeof this.togglebox != "undefined") {
            this.persistdays = (this.togglebox.checked) ? this.persistdays : -1;
            this.cookiestr = (this.togglebox.checked) ? this.cookiestr + "toggleboxid:on;" : this.cookiestr
        } else {
            this.cookiestr = this.cookiestr.substr(0, this.cookiestr.length - 1) + ";"
            setCookie(this.cookiename, this.cookiestr, this.persistdays)
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in my comment it will test the type of the input element to be 'text'. If you'd like to add textareas in the cookie you could change that line to:

```
if (this.fields[i].type == "text" || this.fields[i].type == 'textarea') {
```

That should work.

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the code you've got so far?